# Given a single point in a random set of points, find adjacent points using d3 voronoi

Tags: javascript, d3.js

If I have a set of points:

```
var sites = d3.range(30)
.map(function(d) { return [Math.random() * width, Math.random() * height]; });
```

and a single point

```
var this_site = site[0]
```

How do I find the set of all points which are 'adjacent' to `this_site`?

Comment: You could use [`diagram.find()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-voronoi#diagram_find). The documentation has a link to a nice [example](http://bl.ocks.org/Fil/1b7ddbcd71454d685d1259781968aefc).

Comment: Thank you.  I did check that documentation.  Perhaps I misunderstood.  It says that `.find()`  "Returns the nearest site to point ".  But I want the set of 'adjacent' points - i.e. the set of points in adjacent voronoi polygons.  I'm currently reading through the code in the example you provided, which does seem to do what I want.  I'm just not sure how it does it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to use `d3.voronoi` for this.

```
var diagram = voronoi(sites);
var links = diagram.links()
var polygons = diagram.polygons()
polygons.forEach(function(p) {
  p.adjacent = false
})

var this_site = sites[0] 
var this_polygon = polygons[0] 
var counter = 1
links.forEach(function(l) {
  if (l.source == this_site || l.target == this_site) {

    //get corresponding polygons
    polygons.forEach(function(p) {
      if (p.data == l.target || p.data == l.source) {
        p["adjacent"] = true
      } 

    })
  }

})
```

Here's a working example:
http://blockbuilder.org/RobinL/76580040f9795503ae9586a9b367aa51